# How to apply some sorting to OpenGL objects based on their Vertices in relation to camera

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, rajawali

I'm having a whole lot of trouble with working with transparency in OpenGL. Currently I am working with the Rajawali library example 2000PlanesExample.java found here...

https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali

It may not be available in the library but I'm sure there are capabilities within OpenGL. How and where can/should Vertices be sorted?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite a problem to deal with in OpenGL, have a look at [this OpenGL article](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting)

Comment: This is a good start. I'm hoping for some coded examples of sorting. It seems to me that it is a huge issue with little written on how to achieve simple sorting. I'm looking to only use z-sorting in relationship to the camera.